# How to chain constructors in Structuremap?

Tags: c#, structuremap

Is there a way to chain the constructors in Structuremap? I would want a more succinct code - basically trying to get rid of the `new` keyword in codebase.

Currently what I have:

```cs
container.Configure(c =>
{
    c.For<IDataContext>()
        .Singleton()
        .Use(new CarDataContextWrapper(new CarDataContext(Settings.Default.ConnectionString)
        {
            CommandTimeout = 60
        }));
});
```

To inject in the constructor parameters, I would want to using `.Ctor` declaration. But how would I do it for the second class that I want to initialize?

```cs
container.Configure(c =>
{
    c.For<IDataContext>()
        .Use<CarDataContextWrapper>()
        .Ctor<CarDataContext>().Is(x=>); // HOW TO SET THIS?
});
```

Comment: If both `CarDataContextWrapper` and `CarDataContext` are implementations of `IDataContext`, then what you have is a *decorator pattern*. See the [StructureMap Decorator Documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/interception-and-decorators/) for examples of how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

```
container.Configure(c =>
{
    c.For<IDataContext>()
        .Use<CarDataContextWrapper>("getting context", ctx=>
        {
            return ctx.GetInstance<CarDataContextWrapper>();
        });
        // Also need to tell SM how to build CarDataContextWrapper
});
```